# Android Management API Auto Wipe after one week of device offline or shutdown

Tags: android, mdm, android-management-api

I am trying [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies), and enrolling devices.

1. I switched off 3 devices and leave them off about 1 week.
2. Then, after 1 week, I turned on those devices and they got factory reseted automatically.
3. And I dig the documentation, and found out Auto Wipe feature.

Policy:

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/xxx/policies/MyPolicy2",
  "version": "35",
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "game.puzzle.blockpuzzle",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "as.com.frute",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "com.jetstartgames.chess",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "com.brainium.sudoku.free",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },
  ],
  "maximumTimeToLock": "1800000",
  "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
  "persistentPreferredActivities": [...],
  "statusBarDisabled": true,
  "keyguardDisabled": true,
  "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true,
  "autoTimeRequired": true,
  "appAutoUpdatePolicy": "ALWAYS",
  "advancedSecurityOverrides": {
    "developerSettings": "DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_ALLOWED"
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, I cannot seem to fix it. I already tried ***policyEnforcementRules*** without success. If anyone can help me find the solution, it will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edited: Settings I tried:

```
{
"policyEnforcementRules": [
    {
      "settingName": "passwordPolicies",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "encryptionPolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "keyguardDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedInputMethods",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedAccessibilityServices",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "applications",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "maximumTimeToLock",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "screenCaptureDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "cameraDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "keyguardDisabledFeatures",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "defaultPermissionPolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "openNetworkConfiguration",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "systemUpdate",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "accountTypesWithManagementDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "addUserDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "adjustVolumeDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "factoryResetDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "installAppsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "mountPhysicalMediaDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "modifyAccountsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "safeBootDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "uninstallAppsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "statusBarDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "keyguardDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "minimumApiLevel",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "statusReportingSettings",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "bluetoothContactSharingDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "shortSupportMessage",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "longSupportMessage",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "passwordRequirements",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "wifiConfigsLockdownEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "bluetoothConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "cellBroadcastsConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "credentialsConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "mobileNetworksConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "tetheringConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "vpnConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "wifiConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "createWindowsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "networkResetDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "outgoingBeamDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "outgoingCallsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "removeUserDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "shareLocationDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "smsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "unmuteMicrophoneDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "usbFileTransferDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "ensureVerifyAppsEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedInputMethods",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "stayOnPluggedModes",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "recommendedGlobalProxy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "setUserIconDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "setWallpaperDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "choosePrivateKeyRules",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "alwaysOnVpnPackage",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "frpAdminEmails",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "deviceOwnerLockScreenInfo",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "dataRoamingDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "locationMode",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "networkEscapeHatchEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "bluetoothDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "blockApplicationsEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "installUnknownSourcesAllowed",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "debuggingFeaturesAllowed",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "funDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "autoTimeRequired",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedAccessibilityServices",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "appAutoUpdatePolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "kioskCustomLauncherEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "skipFirstUseHintsEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "privateKeySelectionEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "encryptionPolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "usbMassStorageEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permissionGrants",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "playStoreMode",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "setupActions",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "passwordPolicies",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 1
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 2
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same policy for all your devices? Might it be possible that mutiple devices shared the policy and when you deleted one among them it reset the rest as well.

Wipe Action doesn't reset within 10 days unless set explicitly
https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#wipeaction

Comment: Yes the same policy for all devices. But the policy is still there, and the total devices using the same policy is 10, but only 3 of them which I leave them switched off got reset.

Comment: Have you tried calling [Devices.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) and checking the JSON response “status”? Has a device still been found?

Can you mention what specific setting you have tried without success when using [policyEnforcementRules](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#policyenforcementrule)?

Comment: Devices.get does not contain the devices anymore, because I think they are deleted. 
The settings I tried are added to OP, I did tried to reproduce it with 2 days wipe, not a week.